# Column to ignore dashboard prompt

Tags: obiee

I have a report with 2 columns, both columns measure Sales.  I would like 1 column to filter on a supplier while the second column would be overall sales so that I can compare the sales of the supplier to the total sales.  This report would be used on a dashboard, however I cannot figure out how to get the total sales column to ignore the prompt for the supplier.  Is there any clauses I can use to ignore the dashboard prompt for this one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method:**

1. The prompt sets the variable
2. Report A calls on the variable to tell it what to include
3. Report B calls on the variable to tell it what to exclude

**How-to**

Setup Prompt for “INCLUDE” variable.
Notice the "Set a variable" is set to Presentation Variable:
[image]

**Report A**
Report Filter: Setup Report Variable to accept “Include”:
[image]

**Report B**
**Save a copy of the report and say “is not equal to”

To compare the “All Other except for” report
 [image]

Below is a simple example on a dashboard.
With no filter set, notice that the "exclude" side is showing all results:
[image]

A user must then select an item from the prompt (setting the "Include" variable)

Once the user presses apply you notice that the left side is including the selections and the right side is including everything EXCEPT for whats on the left side:
[image]